# Pre-Defined modules showing empty in Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, module, subclass, superclass

Every pre-defined module like UIKIT, CoreData, CoreLocation..etc showing empty and their superclasses throws an error "Couldn't generate swift representation ". Searched everywhere but I  found nothing about it.

Below are the screen shots :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKxau.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PXYG.jpg

Comment: Can you update your question with actual examples?  "showing empty" doesn't mean much without knowing how and where.  Also, which classes do you mean by "superclasses"?

Comment: superclasses like UIViewController class

Comment: here is the actual image of empty module :https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PXYG.jpg

Comment: Is this happening in one project or do you get the same result if you start a new app with one of Xcode's templates?  (Which Xcode version?)

Comment: yeah, this is happening in only one project. I'm using Xcode -version 11.7

Comment: If you know anything about this problem kindly help. Thanks in advance